# how to change radius in rg-gauge-chart in Angular

Tags: angular, chart.js

I want to increase radius 80%. How can i achieve that, Here my code component.ts

```
public canvasWidth = 200;
   public needleValue = 50; 
   public centralLabel = '';
   public bottomLabel = '10'; 
   public options = {
   hasNeedle: true,
   needleColor: 'gray',
   needleUpdateSpeed: 1000,
   arcColors: ['rgb(44, 151, 222)', 'darkgray'],
   arcDelimiters: [30],
   radius:'80%',
   needleStartValue: 10,
   }
```

component.html,

```
 <rg-gauge-chart
                [canvasWidth]="canvasWidth"
                [needleValue]="needleValue"
                [centralLabel]="centralLabel"
                [options]="options"
                [bottomLabel]="bottomLabel"></rg-gauge-chart>
```

plz help me out, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in the [object](https://github.com/HP0281/crediautosAdm/blob/9285d1745bd327969babc995a0e6352170516b95/src/app/layout/dashboardnetworking/dashboardnetworking.component.ts)

```
   {
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        label: 'Series A',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
        borderWidth: '1.5',
        radius: 0,
        fill: false
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it throgh error not known property..!!!

Comment: check the link for sample code